# How To Multiple Insert Data with Checkbox

Tags: php, laravel

I have some data to update status with checkbox

Controller

```php
public function editTargetInProject(Request $request)
    {
        $arr = $request->id;
        foreach($arr as $id){
            $status =  $request->status;
            if($status){
                Target::findOrFail($status)->update(['status' => "DONE"]);
           }
        }
    }
```

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::label('target_name', 'Target Name') }}
  {{ Form::text('target_name', $target->name, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Target Name' ]) }}
  {{ Form::text('id[]', $target->id, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Target Name' ]) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">    
  {{ Form::label('status', 'Status') }}
  <br>
  @if($target->status == "DONE")
    <input type="checkbox" class="minimal" name="status_{{$target->id}}" id="status" checked>
  @else 
    <input type="checkbox" class="minimal" name="status_{{$target->id}}" id="status">
  @endif
</div>
```

When I update the data all of the data updated to "DONE", I just want to update data where the checkbox is TRUE. 
[image: photo]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an value attribute to your inputs

```
<input type="checkbox" VALUE="DONE" class="minimal" name="status_{{$target->id}}" id="status" checked>
```

and in your for loop, you are missing an id after $request->status_{id}

Try the following

```
public function editTargetInProject(Request $request)
{
    $arr = $request->id;

    foreach($arr as $id){
        $status_id = 'status_' . $id;
        $status =  $request->$status_id;

        if($status){
            Target::findOrFail($status)->update(['status' => "DONE"]);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: error "No query results for model [App\Target].",  I think error at Target::findOrFail($status)

Comment: Try . Target::findOrFail($id)